# How to check required file extensions in form validation in laravel without file_info() extension

Tags: php, validation, laravel

In my laravel application i need to check whether uploading files are of specified types.
For that i checked it using 'mimes:' in validation rules and its worked in my local system. see the code below.

```
public static $rules=array(
         "name"=>"required|min:3",
         "image"=>"required|mimes:jpg,png,gif"
          );
```

But when i uploaded it in my shared hosting its showing a error that php file_info extension is missing. And i contacted server administrator and he said that its not possible to enable file_info extension. 
 So what should i do now, how should i validate this ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) (`Deprecated`), check the [first function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php#87856) on `User Contributed Notes` on `PHP Manual`. Also you may check [this article](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/php-alternative-to-the-depreciated-mime_content_type-function-and-fileinfo-functions/). You may use it like:

```
$type = mime_content_type($filename);
```

P/S: You should think about to change your hosting company.